# properties synthesize and iVars

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar, synthesize

*Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Objective-C*

I have a couple of questions related to @property and @synthesize.

Let's say I have property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

1- I know that on Xcode 4.4+ you can skip doing @synthesize for the properties as they are automatically done. So I assume that the *iVar* generated should be the same as the name of the property right? In general, If I do `@synthesize name;` the *iVar* would be the same as the name of the property?

2- I know that `@synthesize name = _name;` is used when I have manually declared a private variable with the name of _name and I want to make the compiler use it as my property's *iVar*.
I need to know, what happens if I do `@synthesize name = _name;` **WITHOUT** actually having a private variable declared.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455577/objective-c-should-i-assign-the-variable-and-create-a-property-or-is-just-one-o

Answer (score 1):

1. If I'm not mistaken, the default iVars that are generated start with an underscore. I.e.: the default iVar for the property `name` would be `_name`.
2. The iVar `_name` will be generated for the property `name`. No need to manually create any iVar when @synthesize does the job for you, though there won't be any issues if you do want to manually add them.

Comment: Yes, in Xcode 4.4+ you only need `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;`. This will set up the property, accessors and ivars for you. The only time you need to actually use @synthesize is if you are overriding both the getter AND the setter.

Comment: As far as I know, the iVar that is generated has the same name as the property, the distinction between the two is if you use `.` notation to access it.  ie the difference between `myVar = value` and `self.myVar = value`

Comment: @DanF the ivar produced is the same name as the property with an underscore before it. i.e. `self.someValue == _someValue`

Comment: In my code, if I try to access something that is named as one of my synthesized properties with an underscore before it, I get an unrecognized identifier error